# Page Margins for printing in CSS

Tags: html, css, printing

I searched a lot before asking here, but didn't find an answer for my question.

I want to insert top and bottom margin for my website page when printed, so I used the normal `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` for the printed div but it affected on the first sheet only! so I used this as explained in W3C CSS2.1 Specifiction:

```
@page {
    margin-top: 5cm;
    margin-bottom: 5cm;
}
```

but no effect in Firefox Print Preview or Print to PDF. so how can I insert top and bottom margin (for each printed sheet) via CSS? or is there any trick to do this in Firefox?

Comment: Similar to [CSS page headers - how to use print margins?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347992/css-page-headers-how-to-use-print-margins). This feature is not well supported.

Comment: I red it before, so I said: is there any trick to do this in firefox?

Comment: Now works fine in Firefox 35.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Both

```
 @page {
    margin-top: 5cm;
    margin-bottom: 5cm;
 }
```

and

```
@media print {
     body {margin-top: 50mm; margin-bottom: 50mm; 
           margin-left: 0mm; margin-right: 0mm}
}
```

work fine in Firefox 35

Comment: The second example will not add margins on every page if you print multiple pages. The first one is the correct solution.

Comment: The first one doesn't work on safari though.

Answer (score 3):

This should work even in firefox

```
 @media print {
     #main{margin:100px 0;}
 }
```

The "@media print" will make sure the style is only used when printing.