# CSS Print stylesheet - padding on the second page

Tags: css, printing

I'm designing a print stylesheet for a document which will run to a few pages. I want every page to have a company logo at the top, and top padding of 5 centimeters, so I did this:

```
body {
 background:url(logo.png) no-repeat center top;
 padding-top:5cm;
}
```

The logo appears on each page as requested, perfectly. But the top padding only appears on the FIRST page, and every subsequent page has padding-top of zero.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I get the top padding on EVERY page?

Answer (score 1):

This may be because `padding` is counted relative to `body` tag. Use `padding-top` style with immediate wrapper element after `body` tag.

Comment: by 'immediate wrapper element of body' do you mean the HTML tag or BODY > DIV?

Comment: BODY > DIV element, which have actual content wrapping.

Comment: but I don't know when an element will break to the next page...it could be in the middle of that DIV.

I suppose I *could* use page-break-before:always before the DIV...

Comment: page breaks are essential part of print stylesheet. Are you using it.