# Removing elements that appear when printing, using print.css stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

## Problem

I'm currently using a stylesheet `print.css` to remove elements and some styling to create a printer-friendly page, but I can't seem to remove four things that appear in the corners of the page, but are not in the HTML: `pagination`, `date printed`, `title of page`, `URL of page`

### Possible solution?

I've seen this example from the LA Times that shows elements that are not in the HTML, but typically appear when printed being removed: http://graphics.latimes.com/oscar-bingo-2015/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few posts on the subject here on StackOverflow:

- [Remove header and footer from
  window.print()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228088/remove-header-and-footer-from-window-print)
- [Removing page title and date when printing web page (with
  CSS?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573603/removing-page-title-and-date-when-printing-web-page-with-css)
- [Can I remove the URL from my print css, so the web address doesn't
  print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192806/can-i-remove-the-url-from-my-print-css-so-the-web-address-doesnt-print)
- [How to remove the URL from the printing
  page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585254/how-to-remove-the-url-from-the-printing-page)
- [Disabling browser print options (headers, footers, margins) from
  page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page)

Looks like it works by using the [`@page` media property](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/page.html) in combination with the print media property:

```
@media print {
    @page { margin: 0; }
  }
```

However, it only seems to work in Chrome (for the moment). Firefox [can be made](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23778125/2018047) to oblige, though. Elsewhere, it was suggested to create PDF on the fly - or to use JavaScript to set at least the page title to an empty string.

Also, I'd question why you'd want to hide something your users are usually used to have control over.

To answer your question, though: The LA Times use bootstrap, which sets the page margin as follows:

```
...@page{margin:.5cm}...
```

Comment: `@media print {
  @page { margin: 0; }
  body { margin: 1.6cm; }
}`

Comment: The problem with this method is that you (obviously) end up with all the content right against the edge of the page. Muhammad's addition prevents that from happening, but at the cost of any subsequent pages having no margin between their content and the top of the page. Setting the page margin to .5cm is the best solution I've found so far, but of the browsers I've tested it only works properly in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

That's some browser specific printed info. You can't change that, the user has to set its printing properties correctly.

See also: [Removing page title and date when printing web page (with CSS?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573603/removing-page-title-and-date-when-printing-web-page-with-css)

EDIT: this happens to be doable, but I have no idea how.

Comment: I've seen this recently and their printed page doesn't seem to have those things, wondering how they might have done it: http://graphics.latimes.com/oscar-bingo-2015/

Comment: Wow, you're right! I have no idea how they did this.