# @Print mode - ignore website title tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to ignore the website title in `print mode`, follwing [how to hide element in print mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page), I have tried:

```
<title class="hidden-print">site title..</title>
```

And CSS:

```
   @media print{
        .hidden-print {
            display: none !important;
        }
   }
```

But still the title is visable in `print mode`.

BTW - can I hide the date next to the title in print mode?

Comment: Yes but it is not the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use this and then set margins according to your needs. This will remove the headers and backgrounds from the printer settings.

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    @page 
    {
        size:  auto;
        margin: 0mm;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

> BTW - can I hide the date next to the title in print mode?

Are you talking about the footer/header elements : title and date when you print a webpage?  It depends of your browser

[Removing page title and date when printing web page (with CSS?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573603/removing-page-title-and-date-when-printing-web-page-with-css#2573612)