# Print The Receipt Only Using PHP or JS

Tags: javascript, php, printing

So I am just learning php and creating a OPG Clinic Management System as my first project. I am not watching any tutorials or reading books I am learning on the go. For example I didn't know what CRUD is until I needed to implement that in the System.

Right Now I am facing an issue where I am unable to print only the receipt section and not the page like I don't want the even the top parts of the page where they show the title of page number btw I don't have receipt printer to test in yet.

So I want to print only [section within this border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g17h.png). but some how I keep seeing a entire page on the print window and it's probably going to print the entire thing.

Now I don't wanna be like using some PHP framework, I want to keep the whole project vanilla.

I tried a few answers on StackOverFlow where they were using JS but they are still showing the whole page, I even removed the headers and footer from the page, but I see the page title and number on the [print window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da8q8.png). I don't want all this white space titles and other description.

EDIT:

```
<?php include("../../../templates/head.php");
require_once("../../../.config/dbconfig.php");

if (isset($_GET['reportID'])) {
    $fetchedReportID = $_GET['reportID'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM opd_Reports WHERE reportID = $fetchedReportID";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi');
    $currentDate = date('Y-m-d');

    if ($row) {
        $patientID = $row['patientID'];
        $patientName = $row['patientName'];
        $doctorName = $row['doctorName'];
        $reportName = $row['reportName'];
        $reportDate = $row['reportDate'];
        $reportFee = $row['reportFee'];
        $reportID = $row['reportID'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM opd_Patients WHERE patientID = $patientID;";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        if ($row) {
            $patientMail = $row['patientMail'];
            $patientNumber = $row['patientNumber'];
            $patientAge = $row['patientAge'];
            $patientGender = $row['patientGen'];
            $patientCnic = $row['patientCnic'];
            $secretKey = $row['secretKey'];
        }?>
        <div class="w-full p-3 sm:p-5" id="printReceipt">
            <div class="mx-auto max-w-[440px] px-4">
                <div class="bg-white relative shadow-md rounded-lg border border-black overflow-hidden">
                    <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-[90%] mx-auto py-6">
                        <div class="mb-4 w-40 h-40 mx-auto">
                            <!--- Logo --->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="px-8">
                        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 mb-3">
                            <h1 class="font-semibold text-start text-sm">Report ID: <span class="font-normal"><?php echo $reportID ?></span></h1>
                            <h1 class="font-semibold text-end text-sm">Report Date: <span class="font-normal"><?php echo $reportDate ?></span></h1>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="mb-3"/>
                        <div class="grid grid-cols-6 mb-6">
                            <h1 class="font-semibold col-span-3 text-start text-sm">Name: <span class="font-normal"><?php echo $patientName ?></span></h1>
                            <h1 class="font-semibold col-span-3 text-start ms-2 text-sm">Secret Key: <span class="font-normal">  <?php echo $secretKey ?></span></h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid grid-cols-6 mb-6">
                            <h1 class="font-semibold col-span-3 text-start text-sm">CNIC: <span class="font-normal"><?php echo $patientCnic ?></span></h1>
                            <h1 class="font-semibold col-span-1 ms-1 text-center text-sm">Age: <span class="font-normal">  <?php echo $patientAge ?></span></h1>
                            <h1 class="font-semibold col-span-2 text-center text-sm">Gender: <span class="font-normal">  <?php echo $patientGender ?></span></h1>

                        </div>
                        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 mb-6">
                            <h1 class="font-semibold text-start text-sm">Fee: <span class="font-normal"> <?php echo $reportFee ?></span></h1>
                            <h1 class="font-semibold text-end text-sm">Receipt Date: <span class="font-normal"><?php echo $currentDate ?></span></h1>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="py-2">
                        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 mb-6">
                            <h1 class="font-semibold text-center text-sm">View Your Reports Here:<br><span class="font-normal">website url</span></h1>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="py-2">
                        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 mb-6">
                            <span class="font-normal text-xs">Thank you for choosing Digital Dental Diagnostics. If you have any
questions or concerns regarding your procedure or payment,
please contact us at info@xyzdentalclinic.com or
+1 (800) 123-4567.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="bg-black text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-lg font-semibold" onClick="printdiv('printReceipt');">Print</button>
        <script>
            function printdiv(elem) {
                var header_str = '<html><head><title>' + document.title  + '</title></head><body>';
                var footer_str = '</body></html>';
                var new_str = document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML;
                var old_str = document.body.innerHTML;
                document.body.innerHTML = header_str + new_str + footer_str;
                window.print();
                document.body.innerHTML = old_str;
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    <?php }
} else {
    echo '<h3 class="mb-2 text-xl font-bold text-orange-600">You Need To Upload/Select A Report First, Before You Can Print Receipt</h3>';
}
include ("../../../templates/footer.php");
```

Comment: You might consider using a [print stylesheet or media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Printing) (MDN). Also see: [Removing page title and date when printing web page (with CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573603/removing-page-title-and-date-when-printing-web-page-with-css).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print the contents of a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div) - enclose what you want to print in a DIV first

Comment: @KenLee I have something similar this but it still shows the page data    https://www.coderstool.com/cs/NxXZ3j see the Print Window image linked in the question.

Comment: If you are just concerned with those small text appearing in header and footer, Then  you can disable that using options in print window itself. Just go to More Settings and uncheck 'Headers and Footers'

Comment: yes know that but can't I disable them by default? Like if someone print's the receipt and doesn't disable them that would print that whole page right?

Comment: Since you haven't shown any code, it's not clear how anyone could help you. I would advise you spend some time understanding the difference between what happens on the *server* (in your case, PHP) and what happens in the *browser* (rendering HTML and CSS, running JS). That will save you time jumping around between unrelated concepts, and focus on one part of the problem at a time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @IMSoP I have updated the answer and added my code